# UNIQUE constraint failed: sqlite database : android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, unique-constraint

I am trying to insert values in table. But there is only one value inserted. I am getting an error in log cat when I am trying to insert new values.

Log cat shows :

```
abort at 13 in [INSERT INTO event(totalminutesfrom,dayofweek,title,location,totalminutesto,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: event.id
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting totalminutesfrom=694 dayofweek=null title=qxs location=Eded & Mariz totalminutesto=0 id=0
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: event.id (code 1555)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.EventTableHelper.addEvent(EventTableHelper.java:76)
01-24 11:34:39.764 7763-7763/com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.example.siddhi.timetablelayout.AddEventActivity$5.onClick(AddEventActivity.java:217)
```

Its showing error on these two lines while inserting row.

```
db.insert(TABLE, null, values);

   db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle,dayOfWeek,totalMinutesFrom, totalMinutesTo,location));
```

EventTableHelper

```
public class EventTableHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String TABLE = "event";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK = "dayofweek";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_FROM = "totalminutesfrom";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_TO = "totalminutesto";



    public EventTableHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //createTable(db);
    }

    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK +"TEXT" + KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_FROM +"INTEGER"
                + KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_TO + "INTEGER" +  KEY_LOCATION + "TEXT" +  ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);

    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
       // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

      //  createTable(db);

        // Create tables again
        //onCreate(db);
    }

    // code to add the new contact
    public void addEvent(EventData event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, event.getId());
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayofWeek());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_FROM,event.getFromMinutes());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_TO,event.getToMinutes());
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // code to get the single contact
   EventData getEvent(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK, KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_FROM,KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES_TO,KEY_LOCATION }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
       EventData eventData = new EventData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
               cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getInt(4),cursor.getString(5));

        return eventData;
    }



    // code to get all contacts in a list view
    public List<EventData> getAllEvents() {
        List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                EventData event = new EventData();

                event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                event.setDayofWeek(cursor.getString(2));
                event.setFromMinutes(cursor.getInt(3));
                event.setToMinutes(cursor.getInt(4));
                event.setLocation(cursor.getString(5));
                // Adding contact to list
                conList.add(event);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return conList;
    }
}
```

How to solve this??

Comment: You're trying to insert an already existing id. Since the key is UNIQUE, you can't.

Comment: what code should i edit? @ Hrundi V. Bakshi

Comment: I'd make the key an AUTOINCREMENT one. And then I'd not pass the ID, since it would be automatically generated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45299979/6665568  . This answer fully fixed the issue for me . Handles cases if u directly wanna replace if row already present.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code probably violates primary key's uniqueness constraint on a `KEY_ID` field.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Make sure that your `EventData.getId()` returns unique values per object. For now, I don't see you pass any identifier to its constructor and perhaps all the events are inserted with the same `id` value.
2. If you don't care about generating ids by yourself, you can add `AUTOINCREMENT` setting to your `KEY_ID` column definition. This way `KEY_ID` field will be filled automatically and each row will have its own, unique value. Once there, don't forget to remove adding `KEY_ID` to `ContentValues` by yourself.

Comment: thank u so much... second solution worked for me...Did not insert the id..@Mateusz Herych

Comment: Wow, first one is working for me thanks, @Mateusz Herych

Comment: A question is, could we surround the insert with a try catch ?

Comment: i guess no, because insert is done by a thread asynchronously

Answer (score 118):

For developers using [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). You can use

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)  // or OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE
```

in DAO according to [Insert Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert)

Comment: but it's just going to replace an existing row... if you really want to update the item then you should use `@Update`, `@Insert` is for adding new items

Comment: Thanks. This answer should be accepted instead of above one.

Comment: BE AWARE IF YOU USE CASCADE DELETION it will remove all related objects to this related object

Comment: I am still getting the exception even with `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE/IGNORE`. My composite primary key is not unique, but I would like room to just ignore these cases instead of crashing with `SQLiteConstraintException`. How can I fix?

Answer (score 15):

If you use **Room** then instead of `@PrimaryKey` you should use `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

and make your id variable optional:

`@Entity(tableName = "contact_table")
data class Contact(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Long?,
                   @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
                   @ColumnInfo(name = "phone") val phone: String)`

and then when adding a new item, pass `null` as id, `insert` func will return new id, add it to your object

```
val contact = Contact(null, name, phone)
contact.id = ContactRoomDatabase.getDatabase().contactDao().insert(contact)
```

Comment: make the `id` nonnull is also ok. Pass `0` to id, `insert` func will also return new id

Answer (score 9):

This is the case of duplicate id of the record in the database. Just clear the app storage and try again. A good solution would be adding below in your Dao class.

```
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

Correct solution to this problem is to make sure that the id is unique. Please have a look at this [Google Codelabs Room Example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view)

Another way to avoid this would be adding    `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

Answer (score 7):

The table has a unique constraint on it.  That means that only one row can exist with a given ID value.  If you're trying to change some of the values for a row, use UPDATE not INSERT.  If you're trying to add this row, you need to either give it a different, unique ID or you need to delete the pre-existing row first.  Which of these is the right answer depends on what your app is doing.

Answer (score 6):

Try checking if the ID is already existed. If true, do not insert, because you already have the row with this ID.

Answer (score 4):

My mistake was, I tried to fill `ID` column though it was already defined   as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Answer (score 4):

*For Kotlin model classes*

If you're assigning a **default value** to the primary key like this:

```kotlin
data class MyModel(
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = defaultValue
)
```

**Make sure default value is `0` for `Long` and `Int` types.**

---

From the `autoGenerate` comment:

> If the field type is `long` or `int` (or its TypeConverter converts it to a `long` or `int`), `Insert` methods treat `0` as **not-set** while inserting the item.

In my case, I used `-1` as the defaultValue and this error was occurring.

Answer (score 2):

make id column id integer autoincrement, and do not put the id value into content values.

Answer (score 1):

I originally put the new unique constraint infant of the old one. Instead make sure you're current unique column is first:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (client_id TEXT unique, remote_id INT unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was that I forgot to add `db.execSQL(YOUR_TABLE);` in my `DbHelper`

Answer (score 0):

Guys i had the same problem and i cleared my local database from android settings and a clear run the app, that is work for me. Maybe you made a little change in db and you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by didn't insert the primary key manually when it is autoGenerate, this means that instead of putting value in the insert method for id, try to create an instance of entity class and use it in the insert method