# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException in android

Tags: android

**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:**

Logcat :

> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Email_ID=1234567 USER_ID=abcd13
>   Password=a@g.com Mobile=1234567890 Name=asdf
>                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint
>   failed: User.USER_ID (code 1555)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
>   Method)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
>                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
>                             at edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.DatabaseHelper.saveUserData(DatabaseHelper.java:555)
>                             at edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:80)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>       Application terminated.
>       1 
>       source  edit  rollback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNIQUE constraint failed: sqlite database : android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980137/unique-constraint-failed-sqlite-database-android)

Comment: i cant find solution it appears whenever i try to insert values in signup form

Comment: the unique constraint failed error i cant solve it

Comment: Slightly meta question, why did you rollback Nilesh's edit to make your question effectively unreadable again?

Answer (score 3):

Your database already has row with USER_ID=adcd13, therefore you must either update the row or remove it and insert again.

Comment: can someone contact me my exams r there final year project submission i need to solve this...

Comment: Did you try to insert your data in empty database? I am sure, it will work fine. Because your error **E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Email_ID=1234567 USER_ID=abcd13...** says  ** UNIQUE constraint failed: User.USER_ID**